# What kind of media query stack would you use for full-width header background-image?

Tags: css, media-queries

I often use a header with a full width background-image like this page http://thegreatdiscontent.com/adam-lisagor

What kind of media query -stack would you use for the background image? 
I would like mobile devices to use images that are not too big in filesize, but also have retina devices have retina-images. 
So maybe have something like a one big media query for retina macs, maybe one with really compressed image with retina size for the retina ipads. Maybe one for small mobile devices, retina and non-retina..? 
It get's pretty complicated and of course I'd like not to have a list of 20 media queries to target different screen sizes with different resolutions and different (assumed) internet speeds.

Thoughts? What devices would you prioritice?

Thank you.

Comment: I'd suggest media queries dependent on width than devices and offcourse the pixel-ratio like the one Here: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/

Comment: If you look carefully, your example site isn't using a bg image for the full page effect etc at all. It's actually an inline image right in the HTML. Background images are very hard to make responsive as we have very few scaling options available to us.

Comment: I use a transparent png that has the aspect ratio of the wanted image, and then use css background image if I want to serve different sized files for different displays.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand the point of CSS media queries. They won't change the file size being served. CSS is just client side script. If you want to serve images with a smaller file size for smaller screens or slower internet connections, you need to do that on server side.

Take a look at Adaptive Images to do that: http://adaptive-images.com/

Media queries only allow you to resize the original image, so it still loads the full size image, then resizes it.

Comment: With <img> you're correct, but note that we're talking about CSS background-images.

http://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/ Here on Test Four and Test Five show that on most devices only the "correct" file is loaded, accorging to the media query. 

http://timkadlec.com/mq/test3.php Here you can test what your device does.
So you can serve a bigger image to bigger screens etc.

Comment: I stand by everything I said. In those tests, it's not the CSS media queries resizing the image size served, it's the fact that you have multiple images to serve. In my opinion it's a very inefficient way to build a site. What if you ever wanted to change a background image? What if you had multiple background images? You'd have to alter more than one file per background image. 
I think it's better to achieve this with server-side image resizing.

Comment: Note also that using something like Adaptive Images will speed up your entire site as it will effect all images.

Comment: Thank you very much Coop, I'll try out Adaptive Images!

Answer (score 0):

The `background-size` property works nicely to keep a background image filling the available area. E.g.

```
#header {
    background: url(image.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

You can save the image at a large dimension but at a relatively low quality and it will look good on all devices, including retina screens, as explained here: http://blog.netvlies.nl/design-interactie/retina-revolution/

Comment: Yes, that's true as far as it goes but it's not responsive as it will distort the image OR leave a gap at the bottom in most cases. True responsive images have to be inline unless a JS solution can be found.

Comment: `cover` won't distort the image or leave a gap. It keeps the dimension of the image, fills the container, and some of the image may get left out, depending on the dimensions of the container.

Comment: Apologies, I should have said "Crop or Rescale" instead of distort. possibly that's OK in this situation...who knows.

Comment: Thank you for the link. But still, even with heavy compression it would seem pretty wild to serve a 2880px wide image for something like a phone that has a 320px wide display or..? So maybe like one very compressed 2880

Comment: `pretty wild to serve a 2880px wide image` ... Indeed. No need to make it that big.